# Beautifulsoup is it possible to select not unique classes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Sorry, it's me again but I can't figure out the solution to this problem. How can I extract the preparation or in german on the [website](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1521151257327860/Schneemoussetorte-mit-Rhabarber.html) "Zubereitung"? Because the class name is used for many classes. I thought it would be maybe possible to look for a class combination so I can select all classes with name one of the class with name two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `article:has(>h2:contains("Zubereitung")) > .ds-box`:

Select tag with class `ds-box` that is under tag `<article>` that contains title with text `"Zubereitung"`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1521151257327860/Schneemoussetorte-mit-Rhabarber.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
recipe = soup.select_one('article:has(>h2:contains("Zubereitung")) > .ds-box')

print(recipe.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Eine Springform (26 cm) einfetten. Die Eier trennen. Den Backofen vorheizen (Umluft 150°C).
Die Butter mit 125 g Zucker, 1 Prise Salz und 1 Pck. Vanillezucker in einer Rührschüssel mit dem Handrührgerät cremig rühren. Die Eigelbe einzeln unterrühren. Mehl und Backpulver mischen und im Wechsel mit der Milch rasch unterrühren.
Die Hälfte des Teiges in die Form füllen und glatt streichen. Die Eiweiße steif schlagen und dabei 200 g Zucker langsam einrieseln lassen. Weiter schlagen, bis der Zucker sich aufgelöst hat. Die Hälfte des Eischnees auf den Teig in der Form streichen. 2 EL Mandelblättchen darüber streuen und den Tortenboden 25-30 Minuten backen. Abkühlen lassen, aus der Form lösen und völlig auskühlen lassen.
Mit der anderen Hälfte von Teig, Eischnee und Mandelblättchen ebenso verfahren. Diesen Boden vom der Springform lösen und wieder hinein legen.
In der Zwischenzeit ...
```

... and so on.